# Iterate object and array with for loop and add key/value pair

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how to iterate over an object that resembles the following:

```
var json = {"tsn": {
    "events": [
        {
          "title": "Lorem ipsum",  
          "description": "Dolor sit"
        },
        {
          "title": "Duis aute irure",  
          "description": "eu fugiat nulla pariatur"
        },
      ],
    "occurrence": [
        "Music",
        "Party"
      ]
    }    
};
```

I would like to explicitly use a `for` loop as per the code below (and not `for in`)

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    console.log(json.tsn.events[i].title);
}
```

Why does the above code does not get all of `title`?

Secondly, how should I get all the `occurrence`?

And lastly, how I can add to `events` a new key/value pair such as `{"image": "cat.jpg"}` so that the `json` object results like this:

```
var json = {"tsn": {
    "events": [
        {
          "title": "Lorem ipsum",  
          "description": "Dolor sit",
          "image": "cat.jpg"
        },
        {
          "title": "Duis aute irure",  
          "description": "eu fugiat nulla pariatur",
          "image": "dog.jpg"
        },
      ],
    "occurrence": [
        "Music",
        "Party"
      ]
    }    
};
```

Comment: A regular `for` loop is for arrays - you have an object, one of the keys in your object contains an array, so iterate over that key. `for (var i = 0; i < json.tsn.events.length; i++)`

Comment: JSON is a string format. You have an object. I've removed references to JSON in your question, except for the name of your variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I rather use a forEach for this kind of actions. I would do this:

```
var json = {"tsn": {
"events": [
    {
      "title": "Lorem ipsum",  
      "description": "Dolor sit"
    },
    {
      "title": "Duis aute irure",  
      "description": "eu fugiat nulla pariatur"
    },
  ],
"occurrence": [
    "Music",
    "Party"
  ]
}    
};

var events = json.tsn.events;

// loop to iterate through array of tsn events
events.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.title); // to print each of the titles
    item["image"] = "yourImage.jpg"; // will add to each item the image
    // ... do any other item specific operation
});
```

To iterate through occurrence I would do the same thing in a different forEach because they both have different lengths.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using the wrong length.  Use:

```
for (var i=0;i<json.tsn.events.length; i++) { ...
```

And then you should be golden.  For the occurrence, it's much the same -- loop as:

```
for (var i=0;i<json.tsn.occurrence.length; i++) {
    console.log(json.tsn.occurrence[i]);
}
```

And you'll pull those values back also.

Answer (score 1):

`json.tsn.events` is an array.

`json.tsn.events` has a length.

`json.tsn.events[i]` is trying to use the iterator to loop over the array.

`json.length` is trying to compute the iterator using **the top level object** instead of the array.

You need to use the length of the array. `json.tsn.events.length`.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use the `of` keyword you can do this, which is basically the same as running a for loop but less verbose but unable to access indices.

```js
var json = {"tsn": {
    "events": [
        {
          "title": "Lorem ipsum",  
          "description": "Dolor sit"
        },
        {
          "title": "Duis aute irure",  
          "description": "eu fugiat nulla pariatur"
        },
      ],
    "occurrence": [
        "Music",
        "Party"
      ]
    }    
};

for (let event of json.tsn.events)
{
 console.log(event.title);
}

for (let occur of json.tsn.occurrence)
{
 console.log(occur);
}
```